# python reading in multi-column tsv file with row numbers

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

What is the cleanest way of reading in a multi-column tsv file in python with headers, but where the first column has no header and instead contains the row numbers for each row?

This is apparently a common format from files coming from R data frames.

Example:

```
    A      B  C
1   a1     b1 c1
2   a2     b2 c2
3   a3     b3 c3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of outputs do you expect?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with the data afterwards (and if the file is truly a tsv with a \t delimiter). If you just want it in a set of lists you can use the `csv` module like so:

```
import csv
with open("tsv.tsv") as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for line in tsvreader:
        print line[1:]
```

However I'd also recommend the `DataFrame` module from `pandas` for anything outside of simple python operations. It can be used as such:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame.read_csv("tsv.tsv", sep="\t")
```

DataFrames allow for high level manipulation of data sets such as adding columns, finding averages, etc..

Comment: Please consider updating this answer because from_csv is deprecated now. There are no further developments on this. Its suggested to use pd.read_csv now.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313621/no-from-csv-method-in-pandas

Answer (score 6):

`df = DataFrame.from_csv("tsv.tsv", sep="\t")` is deprecated since version 0.21.0

`df = pd.read_csv("tsv.tsv", sep="\t")`  is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

How about using the following native Python codes:

```
with open('tsvfilename') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')[:-1]
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 0: # header
            column_names = line.split()
            # ...
        else:
            data = line.split();
            # ...
```

Comment: Using native python is going to be a lot slower then using pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Import Pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/ABC/DEF/TSV.tsv', sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataFrame.from_csv("tsv.tsv", sep="\t")
```

is not working anymore.
Use

```
df.read_csv("tsv.tsv", sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.read_csv("file.tsv")`

`DataFrame.from_csv()` doesn't work. `DataFrame.read_csv()` isn't right.