# No "from_csv" method in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I try to use `from_csv` method in python 3.7, I receive attribution error:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_csv(adr)

AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'from_csv'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you're calling the function incorrectly try `df = pd.read_csv(adr)`

Comment: Do you mean [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes (12th bullet).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**from_csv** is deprecated now. There are no further developments on this. 
Its suggested to use **pd.read_csv** now.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your-file-path-here")
```

And python warning now says the same -

***main**:1: FutureWarning: from_csv is deprecated. Please use read_csv(...) instead. Note that some of the default arguments are different, so please refer to the documentation for from_csv when changing your function calls*

Comment: Consider using df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None) when your tsv doesn't have header

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('<CSV_FILE>')
```

Answer (score 1):

To read CSV file in a pandas dataframe you need to use the function read_csv. You may try the following code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('adr.csv')
```

The following link will give you an idea about how to use pandas to read and write a CSV file.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html